# Danish language in revtex4-1

Tags: languages, revtex

I have the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

`\today` is translated to danish, but revtex writes "dated: " (ie. "dated: " is not translated).

Furthermore in the author line, revtex writes "and" between authors instead of the danish "og". How to fix this?

Comment: Just a supplement to David's answer: note that revtex4-x is made for making articles for a specific (series of) joyrnal(s), all of which are in English, thus they are not meant for user configuration. I know that some instructors at some Danish physics departments recommended revtex4-x for student assignments, this is, in my opinion, a bad recommendation as it is rather hard to translate it into Danish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`revtex4-1.cls` has

```
\def\Dated@name{Dated }%
\def\Received@name{Received }%
\def\Revised@name{Revised }%
\def\Accepted@name{Accepted }%
\def\Published@name{Published }%
%...
\def\andname{and}
```

so in your preamble you can use

```
\makeatletter
\def\Dated@name{Dated }%
\def\Received@name{Received }%
\def\Revised@name{Revised }%
\def\Accepted@name{Accepted }%
\def\Published@name{Published }%
%...
\def\andname{and}
\makeatother
```

translating as needed